# Почему только в одном модуле ругается на то, что не может найти, а в другом все работает?

Tags: javascript, модули

[image: чуть понятнее скриншот сделал]Есть несколько модулей, почему только в одном ругается на то, что не может найти, а в другом все работает?

[![два окна одной программы][2]][2]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120).

Comment: А файлы у вас в одном месте лежат? Может там где не видит модуля, нет node_modules? Как бы другого дано. Это либо 2 разных проекта со своими репозиториями, либо одно из двух

Comment: Покажите package.json с зависимостями, ну и отдельно проверьте, нет ли ошибки в написании(может js-cookie написано с русскими буквами)

Comment: А если там где нет ошибки (в jsx файле), его переменовать в tsx, ошибка будет?

Comment: @Oliver Patterson да, из за расширения ругался, спасибо. там чуть по другому библиотека устанавливается

Answer (score 0):

Это может и сами IDE выдавать неверный результат, и в разных папках-проектах происходит дело. Чтоб исключить влияние IDE запустите с терминала свое приложение. И если выдаст ошбику - в терминале в той же папке посмотрите усталновлен ли пакет командой `npm ls`

Comment: установлен, но все равно не видит его почему то. а чего сделать то можно?

Comment: @SwaD чуть другой скрин сделал и на нем папка app не видит модуль, а appHeader видит

Comment: npm ls сделайте - посмотрите установлен ли модуль в папках